# Change toggle image form C# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, toggle

I created a toggle group with four toggles and installed swap image to highlighted. In result, I want to have four states for toggle image - background, highlighted, true and false.

That I think, I can do it only with script C#. My attempts to use `toggle.targetGrafic` and `toggle.grafic` doesn't work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LoadQuestion : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Toggle toggleA;
    public Toggle toggleB;
    public Toggle toggleC;
    public Toggle toggleD;
    public Image trueA;
    public Image falseA;
    public Image backA;

    public void CheckAnswer()
    {
        if ( toggleA.isOn )
        {
            toggleA.targetGraphic = trueA; //Resources.Load("Sprites/logo") as Image;
        }
    }
}
```

`CheckAnswer()` I was imported to On Value Changed (Boolean) in engine.
`Resources.Load` - also does not give the result and reporting error:

> You must have a Image target in order to use a sprite swap transition.

Comment: Could you please specify your question? I'm a bit confused as to what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to control Togle's image under certain conditions. At the same time, Toggle must respond to highlighting and pressing.
After the user clicks on Toggle, I check the correctness of the selected answer and want to highlight Toggle green or red.

Comment: Sorry, I meant specify it in your post. It will help others give you a solid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have custom images when toggling on/off, you can use this:
Remove reference to graphic in Toggle component in inspector or by script

```
toggleA.graphic = null;
```

Make reference to **Image** which was that graphic component and change sprite of that image via script;

```
public Toggle toggleA;
public Image toggleAImage;
public Sprite trueA;
public Sprite falseA;
private bool isOn;

private void Start()
{
    toggleA.graphic = null;
}

public void CheckAnswer()
{
    toggleAImage.sprite = isOn ? trueA : falseA;
    isOn = !isOn;
}
```

Not sure what you're trying to do with background and highlighted, but you can setup those conditions in inspector on the Toggle component. Please keep in mind, that toggle consists of 2 elements: background image and "check" image. You can setup highlighted state sprite swap in inspector only for background. My code above is for "check" image.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me either. Could there be a reason in the disabled checkmark ?

Comment: @Belladon the checkmark gameobject should be enabled.

Comment: OK. I turned on the checkmark and added it to the Graphic field. But I still can't replace the sprite from the code.
Also, after my attempts to influence the image and after your code, there is always one result. When pressed, Toggle remains highlighted. Although I only use this sprite for highlighting.

Comment: @Belladon you don't need to add it to graphic. Otherwise it will be controlled by Toggle component (basically turning it on and off, not swaping "check" sprite). As for highlighting, you should also attach some sprite for the normal state on Toggle component.

Comment: Your code works for me too. But now I still can't set the highlight because it interrupts the effect background, which I do with code

Comment: @Belladon what are you putting highlight on? On the background? I think you shouldn't do it by code, just put a sprite on background image for normal state, select sprite swap in Toggle component's transitions, and put highlighted sprite in "highlighted" field. Be sure that "target graphic" there is a background image.

Comment: Maybe I do not need to use Toggle. For example, the button. The task is to light up when hovering and change the sprite after pressing

Comment: @Belladon you can try using button, but it has no on/off state, so you need to control it by script with some bool and change sprites similar to my code. I updated my code to show how it can be achieved

Comment: Thanks, your answers is helpfull